# Compare multiple columns with a column and color duplicate cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a total of 5 columns. First 4 columns have data in 74 rows. 5th column has data in 538 rows. I want to compare the data in 5th column with the data in the remaining 4 columns and after the comparison I want to highlight those values in 4 columns that are in common with the data in 5th column. More to be like coloring those common cells in those first 4 columns. Help is very much appreciated. Below is a screenshot of my entire sheet. For example if 'krbtgt' from 5th column is present in any of the first 4 columns out of all the 74 rows they should get highlighted or the cell should be colored in red for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting can do this.

Select Cell `A1`.

Click *Conditional Formatting* and then *New Rule...*

Chose the option *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.

Paste the following formula into the formula bar:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((A1=$E$1:$E$538)+0)>0
```

Choose the formatting you desire for this condition (e.g. to change background to yellow).

Then, apply this formatting rule to the desired range (presumably `A1:D74`).

This will highlight any cell in the range `A1:D74` that is equal to any entry in the range `E1:E538`.

See below for example. (Note in this example below, blank cells are highlighted because the `E` column contains blank cells.)

[image]

See below for how to apply to your cell range. Apply this to: `=$A$1:$D$74`.

[image]

Comment: I did the same as you stated, =SUMPRODUCT((A1:D74=$E$1:$E$538)+0)>0, but it is not working. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @jeevanreddymandali You did not do what I stated. Please carefully read my answer. It is `= SUMPRODUCT((A1=$E$1:$E$538)+0)>0`. The cell range of `A1:D74` does not appear in the formula itself. Rather, it is simply the range of where you apply the conditional formatting rule.

Comment: @jeevanreddymandali See my answer above, I edited to show how to apply this rule to that range.